# “Transposed .txt file" with random characters, is it possible?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating “transposed” files with random characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166835/creating-transposed-files-with-random-characters)

Hey people,

I am writing a program that creates ".txt" files with random characters, and I want to create transposed ".txt" files with the same data that was writen previously in a random way. Here I add an example of the two ".txt" files as I intend to do.
Think that every letter or number is a random string, for example "A" would be "ih65ds8ds69"

```
FILE1

A|B|C|D|E|F|G|
H|I|J|K|L|M|N|
O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|
V|W|Z|1|2|3|4|


FILE2 (FILE1 transpossed)

A|H|O|V|
B|I|P|W|
C|J|Q|Z|
D|K|R|1|
E|L|S|2|
F|M|T|3|
G|N|U|4|
```

Thes most simmilar thing I've got with the program I attach is:

```
FILE2 (FILE1 transpossed)

A|B|C|D|
E|F|G|H|
I|J|K|L|
M|N|O|P|
Q|R|S|T|
U|V|W|Z|
1|2|3|4|
```

So now I attach the code I have writen so that you can have a look and give me some ideas about how modify it to get what I intend.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int rows, columns, element1; 

char word[10];

    ofstream myfile ("File 1.txt");
    if(myfile)
    srand(1);
    for(rows=0;rows<10;rows++)
    {
        for(columns=0;columns<30;columns++)
        {
            element1 = rand() % 100000 + 1;
            int len = rand () % 4 + 4;
            word [len] = 0;
            while (len) word [--len] = 'A' + rand () % 58;

            myfile<<element1<<word;
            myfile<<"|";
        }
        myfile<<endl;

    }
    myfile.close();


    ofstream myfileS ("File 2.txt");
    if(myfileS)
    srand(1);
    for(columns=0;columns<30;columns++)
    {
        for(rows=0;rows<10;rows++)
        {

            element1 = rand() % 100000 + 1;
            int len = rand () % 4 + 4;
            word [len] = 0;
            while (len) word [--len] = 'A' + rand () % 58;

            myfileS<<element1<<word;
            myfileS<<"|";
        }
        myfileS<<endl;
    }
    myfile.close();



system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Thank you very much for all your help!!! :D

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166835/creating-transposed-files-with-random-characters from same user.

Answer (score 3):

Use a 2-dimensional array -- and change the order of printing :).

Comment: The idea looks really interesting. But it seems a bit hard for me (my knowledge of C++ is still quite basic, but for that I'm learning :D), and I don't see how to use a 2-dimensional array. I imagine that after creating the first file I should save this as a matrix, yeah? But how? and then print this information, right? This would be clear, but as I say the process of creating the 2-dimensional array is not that clear for me... sorry, but could you give me some details?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure - http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/22twodim.html  :)

Comment: Thanks Kornel, I have learnt about 2-dimensional arrays and I have solvented my problem. Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to load the strings from the input file into a 2-dimensional array (MxN).  Then, creating the output file would involve simply iterating down the columns and across the rows.

Your code seems to generate random data for file 1 and file 2.  Please post the code that generates the output that you posted.  Without seeing what you have done, it's difficult to give you any specific advice.

**EDIT:**  Nevermind, I missed the `srand(1)` that you were using to force the same random data to be generated in both loops.

Instead of generating random data and immediately printing it to a file, fill a MxN array with random data values.  Then, iterate through that array twice, printing the data as you go.  One loop will iterate through columns before rows and the other rows before columns.

Comment: The idea looks really interesting. But, taking into account that my knowledge of C++ is quite basic, and I don't see how to load these strings in a matrix as you say... itseems something quite impossible for me now. Could you help me? Some ideas how to work with  2-dimensional array?? First steps how to do it?? How would you modify my code?? where?? Thanks in advance for all your help! :)

Comment: A few links regarding multi-dimensional arrays: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/append-c.html, http://visualcplus.blogspot.com/2006/03/lesson-15-matrixes-and-2d-arrays.html.  Practically any introductory book on C or C++ should cover arrays as well.

Comment: Some questions about your post, how would I fill this random values in a 2-dimensional array? what do you mean with 'iterate through that array twice'? How could I access then to every column and ask to print in a file column per column? Thanks for the links and all the help bta! I'm just have a look right now :)

Comment: Thanks! With the links you provided me my doubts are solvented! Thanks a lot! :)